# Como poner en la vista de un reporte una busqueda en la caja de texto con Microsoft Report builder?

Tags: oracle, powerbi, microsoft, report

Estoy migrando reportes de OBIEE a RS con Microsoft Report Builder.

Mi pregunta es que en OBIEE pueden filtrar en la vista
[Como aquí se ve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Prc.png)

En Report builder no encuentro alguna opción que realice lo mismo, solo que ordene por algun campo, sabrán como puedo hacer eso de OBIEE en Report Builder que puedan escoger en la vista ya generada los campos que desean?

Gracias por su ayuda.

En interactive sorting, solo ordena.